# Using JustSaying SNS and SQS all hookup in AWS but Handler not getting invoked

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

Using [JustSaying 4.0.306](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JustSayin) and configuring the publisher like so:

`_publisher = CreateMeABus
  .InRegion("eu-west-2").WithNamingStrategy(()=>new Naming<T>())
  .WithSnsMessagePublisher<MessageHolder<T>>();`

I'm overriding the naming strategy as when using generics is creates a very verbose name.

```
 public class Naming<T> : INamingStrategy
{
    public string GetTopicName(string topicName, string messageType) 
   { 
      return "topic_" + typeof(T).Name.ToLower(); 
   }

    public string GetQueueName(SqsReadConfiguration sqsConfig, string messageType) 
    { 
      return "queue_" + typeof(T).Name.ToLower(); 
    }
}
```

I'm configuring the subscription end like so:

```
var queuename =  "queue" + typeof(T).Name.ToLower();
        var bus = CreateMeABus.InRegion("eu-west-2")
            .WithNamingStrategy(() => new NamingStrategy<T>())
            .WithSqsTopicSubscriber().IntoQueue(queuename)
            .WithMessageHandler<MessageHolder<T>>(new HandleMessage<T>(_handler));

        bus.StartListening();
```

In AWS the SNS Topic gets created along with the SQS queue's and all the subscriptions etc. When publishing I can see messages flowing into the queue and they are being read from the queue but the `HandleMessage<T>.Handle(MessageHolder<T> message)` never gets invoked.

I can see that the messages are taken from the queue and sometimes they are in flight so something in the JustSaying world is taking them out of the queue but it never gets to the handler.

Anyone failure with this framework have any idea why is there something I have missed or could it be serialization is failing before the handler is getting invoked?

g/